# Create rows based on array

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I have a spreadsheet document that I want to make as efficient as possible. It is used to calculate the quantity-based discounts of a product. The more you buy, the cheaper the unit is.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JxrvA3WPANQeIXqLt-7NFFgyxxKbqr_4rW_Q5ptAvKA/edit?usp=sharing

In the first red cell, call "tiers" I will input the quantities at which the discounts will be applied.

I want to use this array in the table directly underneath, one item per row until we run out of numbers.

I will then enter the percentage values in the right hand side and that will then populate the rest of the fields.

So all I will need to do is enter the cost price, the tiers, and the percentages and this calculator does the rest.

My question is, how do I create new rows based on this array in the correct place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paste in B10 cell and drag down:

```
=B$9-B$9*C10
```

paste in B15 cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(A15:A*VLOOKUP(A15:A, A9:B12, 2)))
```

[image]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qwNlheNs6dn76aC9wTEO1BAolPIjj-Oyws1J7nuh1YM/copy)

Comment: I don't think this is correct, or it does not do what I needed?

Comment: it does exactly what I understood from your question. by putting any number in A column (for example A28) it will calculate the final price in B column based on given discounts for given amounts